# JenaException: Invalid properties file

Tags: java, exception, properties, ontology, jena

I have been working with Jena fine for the first few weeks. However, today tomcat has started spitting out errors.

I think I've narrowed it down to:

```
Caused by: com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.JenaException: Invalid properties file
at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.Metadata.read(Metadata.java:71)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.Metadata.addMetadata(Metadata.java:41)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.Metadata.<init>(Metadata.java:35)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.JenaRuntime.<clinit>(JenaRuntime.java:25)
```

Although, I can't figure out which properties file it means. I've never configured a property file for jena. The only other thing I can think of that requires parsing is my web.xml which doesn't look wrong.

The code that causes the error is:

```
public void getOntModel()
{
    try
    {
        ssn = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
        ssn.read(NS);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("[ONTOLOGY] Failed to read ontology file");
    }
    System.out.println("[ONTOLOGY] Ontology successfully read");
}
```

Specifically:

```
ssn = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
```

Comment: That exception won't tell you very much. Try ex.getCause().printStackTrace(), which will show the original issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source:

- http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.hp.hpl.jena/jena/2.6.3/com/hp/hpl/jena/JenaRuntime.java#JenaRuntime

This is what is happening:

```
 private static String metadataLocation = "com/hp/hpl/jena/jena-properties.xml" ;
 private static Metadata metadata = new Metadata(metadataLocation) ;
```

It seems that it's trying to load the resource specified by metadataLocation. Can you check that your classpath is correct? Especially, check that there are no mixed versions of Jena libraries - if there are, reorder them so the newest are in front of your classpath.

If on some Unix-like system, you can use:

```
find /path/to/lib -name "*.jar"|while read fn; do
   echo ---- $fn
   jar tf $fn|grep jena-properties.xml
done
```

to find the jar that contains that property file - just change `/path/to/lib` to the path where your Jena libraries are located.

Comment: jena-properties.xml is contained in /usr/local/bin/tomcat/webapps/Isengard/WEB-INF/lib/jena-2.6.3.jar; that is the only jena library jar present and I get a different error if I remove it from the classpath.

Comment: Did you check your tomcat classpath?

Comment: TOMCAT_HOME=/usr/local/bin/tomcat/
CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/bin/tomcat/
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj-1.4.2.0/

Can't work out why a problem with the classpath would manifest now with nothing having changed?

Comment: Can you try actually printing it just before the exception line - see this: http://dev-answers.blogspot.com/2006/06/how-do-you-print-java-classpath.html. Also, can you try loading the file as given in the Jena Metadata class (http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.hp.hpl.jena/jena/2.6.3/com/hp/hpl/jena/util/Metadata.java#Metadata, read method) and see what you get - i.e. actually print the InputStream and see whether the output is what you expect.

Comment: If you look here: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.hp.hpl.jena/jena/2.6.3/com/hp/hpl/jena/util/SystemUtils.java#SystemUtils.chooseClassLoader(), you'll see that you can enable the trace-level logging to see which classloader is being used - this might also be useful for debugging the issue.